# Microphone input buffer circuit not behaving as in simulation

Tags: circuit-analysis, audio, analog, filter

I have designed a circuit to interface the [SPW2430HR5H-B](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/218/SPW2430HR5H-B-1290924.pdf) microphone into a dsPIC33 ADC pin.

The circuit has an active LPF and uses the AC coupling capacitor as a HPF to get an output on the frequency range between 500Hz to 3KHz.

According to my simulation, I am getting exactly what I need:

[image]

However, when I test the real circuit already built on a PCB, the lower frequencies seem to be much more amplified than the high frequencies.

I have checked the mic datasheet and it has a flat response in the band of interest so I suppose the culprit is something else.

Could it be excessive parasitic capacitance from the PCB? Acoustics? Something wrong with my circuit?

Thank you

Comment: That's your simulated circuit.  What does the circuit you really built look like?  Your simulation (naturally) leaves out the power supply to the microphone, but it is required for real operation.

Comment: Why does your circuit run from right to left?

Comment: Just a bit of nitpicking: it's good that you make use of the builtin parasitics for the voltage sources, but only using `Cpar` is useless, since only `Rser` converts it from a voltage source into a current source (internally), which means that you have a voltage source with a parallel capacitor (and, thus, useless). You should use either only `Rser` (as you did with `V1`), or both `Rser/Cpar`.

Comment: @JRE Are you saying that an unstable power supply can cause a difference in frequency response? ICs have their corresponding bypass caps and the power supply comes from a transformer followed by an LDO so it is pretty stable

Comment: @a concerned citizen, thanks for the tip

Comment: I'm saying from the simulator diagram, we can't tell if you provided power to the microphone at all.

Comment: Room shape and acoustic properties can make a mockery of testing at low frequencies due to room resonance. Draw proper op-amp symbols is my other advice.